# Django bulk_create while populating ImageField

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying `bulk_create` a list of `Person` objects from some list of raw parsed API data. 
the data contains:

- Id
- Comment
- Image

  ```
     person = raw_api_data[0]
     obj = Person(
          id=person['id'],
          comment=person['comment'],
      )

      if person['image'] is not None:
          obj.image.save(
              '.jpg',
              ContentFile(person['image'].decode('base-64')),
              save=False,
          )
  new_persons.append(obj)

  Person.objects.bulk_create(new_persons)
  ```

I want to be able to avoid creating local image files on file system in case `bulk_create` fails. (`IntegrityError` for example)

Is there any way to avoid creating the file itself before the create process itself while also be able to bulk create all objects with their images?

I did not find any other ideas besides creating the content file before appending the object itself to the bulk list.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, no. If you want you are concerned with a huge bulk list try using the concept of batching where you do a bulk insert every 500 items or so. But you will always have to update the list while doing bulk create.